# Two Created Races. One had copper-based blood and the other iron-based blood

Tags: story-identification, ftl-drive

I once read a sci-fi-story about a group of scientist that used a Feinberg space drive with the aim of terraforming a planet and creating a new race. The group however was divided on how they wanted the race to develop.

One faction wanted the new race's blood hemoglobin to be copper-based much like chlorophyll with the hope that it would be more peaceful while another faction wanted to blood hemoglobin to be iron-based so that the created race would be strong and fierce.

Near the end both factions wanted to establish a Messiah mythos. The faction who created the iron-based race, presented their Christ as strong conquering Messiah while the copper-based race somehow ended with a female "Christ" who suffered and I think died but was resurrected by the creator scientist.

When she was told of the story of Jesus Christ, she broke down and cried in recognition to the bewilderment of the second faction. Could someone please the title of this story and who wrote it?